# Why is this Cheerio attribute selector not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I want to use the following selector normally found in jQuery to create a function that works on its children:

```
var useroverviewHook = $("div[data-pnref='overview'] *[data-overviewsection]");
```

However, it is not working in Cheerio. Nodejs console is reporting

```
console.log($(useroverviewHook).length) is 0
```

even though, when testing in the browser, the value is not 0, multiple elements exists.

First I tought the content is dynamic but if I output

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); res.write(html);
```

data-overviewsection is there. But cheerio says it's not.

Comment: Please include the relevant html code

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1):

First at all, you dont need to use `$()` twise

```
var useroverviewHook = $("div[data-pnref='overview'] *[data-overviewsection]");
console.log(useroverviewHook.length)
```

And you can simplify this selector (remove `*`):

```
div[data-pnref='overview'] [data-overviewsection]
```

Check, maybe you did some mistake when type selectors names and attributes because your syntax is fine.

Also, sometimes browser modify HTML if it was broken when I have similar issues I save response into a file and check response html again.

Comment: It's not working. I put the response in res.write(response.body). I used jquery there and the syntax worked. It's not working on cheerio. The length is 0

Comment: I think I had the same issue - you need to convert $() selection in array 
`$('selector').toArray();`
I too was think what a selection its an array)

Comment: When I run console.log($('div[data-pnref="overview"] [data-overviewsection]')) I get initialize {
  options:
   { withDomLvl1: true,
     normalizeWhitespace: false,
     xmlMode: false,
     decodeEntities: true },
  _root:
   initialize {
     '0':
      { type: 'root',

Comment: get the link which you try to scrape